# how to load returned image from facebook response?

Tags: android, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, request

I'm using this command for Facebook album cover photo, where "tag" is album ID:

```
new Request(session, "/" + tag + "/picture", 
            params, HttpMethod.GET, 
            albumIconImageRequest ).executeAsync();
```

According to documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album/picture

> No fields are returned, instead you will receive the image file itself.

So I'd like to ask for a simple example how could I extract that image from returned Response and load it into ImageView?

```
    private Request.Callback albumIconImageRequest =  new Request.Callback() {
        @Override 
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            imageView.setImageResource(response.getGraphObject.???????????????)
        }
    };
```

**EDIT:** Should I somehow use BitmapFactory for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get image from Facebook JSON object and load it into ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938787/get-image-from-facebook-json-object-and-load-it-into-imageview)

Comment: actually, it should be the other way around. if there is a duplicate already (maybe with some answers), it is better not to create another thread.

Comment: nevertheless, the other thread seems to be deleted now...